# .Net Maui - Binding to backgroundcolor

Tags: .net, button, binding, maui

**How can I set a bacground color for button in ViewModel?**

I want to set color at start (when page is being opened) and be able to change it later. I just have no idea how to do it right.

Here is code that I doesn't work.

xaml

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:ChangeColorModeViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext> 
    
    <Button
        x:Name="Button1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding btnColor}"
        Clicked="BtnCheckColor"/>
```

View model

```
    public partial class ChangeColorModeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChangeColorModeViewModel()
    {
        BtnColor = ColorLose;
    }

    public static Color BtnColor;
    public static Color ColorWin = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
    public static Color ColorLose = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);

    public Color btnColor
    {
        get
        {
            return BtnColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != BtnColor)
            {
                BtnColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(btnColor));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you remove static from "public static Color BtnColor;" and try again? or just better.. write down a full property from scratch. that full property looks a bit off. (tip: write propfull and double click tab button on your keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tataelm suggested, just remove the static from `public static Color BtnColor;` I tested it and it successfully set a background color(**Blue**) for button in ViewModel.

Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

```
  public partial class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Color ColorWin = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);

        private Color _btnCoior;
        public Color btnColor
        {
            get => _btnCoior;
            set
            {
                _btnCoior = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_btnCoior));
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            btnColor = ColorWin;
        }



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)

        {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

        #endregion

      
    }
```